# Can a man make non-sexual love to woman without damaging her hymen ? Are there any examples like this?

Tags: marriage, women, sex

Having [sex with a virgin woman,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52884/having-sex-with-which-women-is-very-big-sin/52885#52885) then refusing to accept her as wife is generally [considered wrong.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201935.html)
As consensual sex with a virgin woman is generally considered as [defacto Gandharva Vivah.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49965/what-is-the-essential-requirement-of-gandharva-wedding-is-penetration-essentia)

But Can a man make non-sexual love to a woman i.e. kiss her, hug her,hold her hands and then not marry her ? Is it also a wrong thing to do ?
Are there any examples like this ?

I think two examples exist -
Parshara having sex with Satyavati then "restoring" her virginity.
Surya telling Kunti that she will remain virgin even after Karna's birth.
Note - Hymen restoring surgery exist even today.

But I want only the examples where non-sexual love was made and then marriage didn't happen.