A question about Gandharva Vivaha?
Harita Smriti says:‘When the girl herself selects the bridegroom, it is Gāndharva.’
Does selecting itself mean marriage is done or actual marriage/union should take place between them to call it vivaha?
Kindly someone share the Harita smriti shloka which speaks about gandharva vivaha..

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49970/34973

This question is similar to: What is the essential requirement of Gandharva wedding ? Is penetration essential for Gandharva Wedding?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you go by the exact meaning of the word vivāha, then the woman/daughter has to be carried (vāha) or taken away.
In case of gāndharva vivāha, the choice and consummation would be key, as this was a way that such relationships were accepted by the society, that accepted ashtavivāha. Just choice alone would be categorised as svayamvara.
In case you are looking for life advice, wrong place, but nowadays The Special Marriage Act, 1954 would be better than the Grihyasutras.
